# If statement in a for loop to stop iteration if a substring is found in a hash value returned by a function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, hash, md5

I have the following code that is seeking, for teaching purposes, to do the following:

1. Function hash, takes the string (let's say "bitcoin") and returns a hash value.
2. The for loop iterates through from 0 to a range and keeps adding "!" to the string "bitcoin" e.g. in iteration 1 = bitcoin, iteration 2 = bitcoin!, iteration 3 = bitcoin!!, iteration 4 = bitcoin!!!, and so on.
3. In each case the hash value is being found for the string (in each iteration a different hash value is being generated due to the concatenated "!" character.
4. I have added an if function to the for loop that should stop and print the hash value IF the value starts with "00".

It is no. 4 at which my code breaks. I've tried various things but think I am missing something very basic.

**Test data**: Please use: "bitcoin"

Expected result: if a hash value returned by the function hash has two leading zeroes in it e.g. starts with 00, then the for loop should stop, and it should print out the the number (i) in the for loop and the actual hash value.

```
import hashlib

def hash(mystring):
    hash_object=hashlib.md5(mystring.encode())
    print(hash_object.hexdigest())


mystring=input("Enter your transaction details (to hash:")


for i in range(100000000000):
    hash(mystring)
    mystring=mystring+"!"
    if "00" in hash(mystring):
        break
    print(hash(mystring))

hash(mystring)
```

**The error I get with input "bitcoin" is:**

```
Enter your transaction details (to hash:bitcoin
cd5b1e4947e304476c788cd474fb579a
520e54321f2e9de59aeb0e7ba69a628c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/testa/Desktop/bitcoin_mine_pythonexample.py", line 14, in <module>
    if "00" in hash(mystring):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
>>>
```

I've also tried this - trying to add a return statement and use a slightly different approach - is this along the right lines?

```
import hashlib

def hash(mystring):
    hash_object=hashlib.md5(mystring.encode())
    print(hash_object.hexdigest())
    if "00" in hash_object:
                return 1
        else:
                return 0

mystring=input("Enter your transaction details (to hash:")


for i in range(100):
    hash(mystring)
    mystring=mystring+"!"
    if hash(mystring)==1":
            print("Found")

hash(mystring)
```

Comment: Your `hash` function isn't returning anything.  All it's doing it printing something, then implicitly returning `None`.  Add a `return` statement.

Comment: @TomKarzes -if you remove the if statement, the for loop will print a 100 or 1000 hash values. I may be misunderstanding what you're suggesting - could you please post an answer with code that solves the problem so I can verify.

Comment: Tom already told you what the problem is: your function doesn't return anything.  You need to fix that.  You seem to have confused `print` and `return`, which suggests that you need to revisit your teaching materials on functions.

Comment: By the way, hash is the name of a built-in function. You should call your function something else.

Comment: You have to return hash_object.hexdigest(), not just the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things.  First, `hash` isn't returning anything, it's just printing the result and then returning `None`.  Change it by removing the `print` and instead returning the hash value.

Second, using `"00" in string` looks for `"00`" anywhere in the string, not just the start.  Also, the main loop calls `hash` three times per iteration.  There's also a final call to `hash` outside the loop which serves no purpose.

The following should do what you want:

```
def myhash(mystring):
    hash_object=hashlib.md5(mystring.encode())
    return hash_object.hexdigest()

mystring=input("Enter your transaction details (to hash:")

while True:
    hashval = myhash(mystring)
    print(hashval)
    if hashval.startswith("00"):
        break
    mystring += "!"
```

Update:  I renamed `hash` to `myhash` to avoid overriding the builtin `hash` function in Python.

Comment: this is just printing the same hash value and not adding the ! to change the hash value with each iteration. Very helpful to explain regarding the return -thank you - as you can see - I've attempted something in the update (see question) but am still not quite there.

Comment: @Compoot Oops, I accidentally left out adding the `"!"` - it's fixed now. Sorry about that - refresh the page and look at the new code.

Comment: so...I couldn't really do this using a for loop could I? ...as in it wouldn't make much sense. I wonder if anyone has any comments on how closely this is useful for teaching about the nonce in bitcoin mining. Would it be appropriate and not voted down to ask a question regarding this?

Comment: @Compoot Well, a `for` loop doesn't make sense since you aren't iterating over anything.  The normal way to code a loop with no exit test in Python is with `while True:`  Even if you had an infinite generator, you'd still need to provide a dummy loop variable and it would be slower and less clear than `while True:`.

Comment: @Compoot By the way I made a minor update to the posted code.  I renamed `hash` to `myhash` to avoid overriding the builtin `hash` function in Python.